# Как обратиться к статическому методу динамически создаваемого класса?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Хочу автоматически создать классы и распихать их по переменным. Пример:

Есть переменная  `var classes = {};` и есть классы `MyClass`, `MyClass2`, `MyClass3`, `MyClass4`. Все они - синглтоны.

Хочу инициализировать все классы и  записать в этот объект так, чтоб обращаться к классам через `classes.MyClass`, `classes.MyClass2` и т.д.

Вот пример класса (другие классы подобные):

```
let _myClassSingleton = Symbol();

class MyClass {

    constructor(enforcer) {
        if (enforcer != _myClassSingleton) 
            throw "Cannot construct singleton";
    }

    static getInstance() {
        if(!this[_myClassSingleton]) {
            this[_myClassSingleton] = new MyClass(_myClassSingleton);
        }
        return this[_myClassSingleton];
    }

    someMethod() { console.log('MyClass/someMethod'); }
}
```

Т.е. обратиться к экземпляру можно только так `MyClass.getInstance();`

Имена всех классов записаны в массиве, т.е.

```
let applicationClasses = ['MyClass', 'MyClass2', 'MyClass3', 'MyClass4'];
```

Как мне инициализировать все эти классы динамически и сложить в объект `classes` ?

Пытаюсь через цикл:

```
for (let className of applicationClasses) {
    // код инициализации классов
}
```

Но если в цикле писать так:

```
classes[className] = className.getInstance();
```

будет выдавать, конечно же, ошибку, что нет метода `getInstance`. Что логично. Ибо это получается, что вызываем метод у строки.

Можно написать так:

```
classes[className]  = eval(className + ".getInstance()");
```

тогда будет все будет работать и можно будет обращаться к классам через `classes.MyClass`, `classes.MyClass2` и т.д. Однако через `eval` не хочется делать.

**Вопрос**: можно ли как-то еще сделать данную вещь или единственный вариант в данном случае только `eval` ?

Comment: какой-то у тебя неправильный синглтон, класс MyClass, а возвращаешь объект Settings

Comment: @Grundy прошу прощения. Просто для примера переименовывал имя. Недопечатал

Comment: классы объявлены в глобальном контексте? или внутри каких-нибудь самовызывающихся функций?

Comment: @Grundy глобально. собраны в одном файле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо строк, в массиве можно хранить непосредственно ссылки на классы, тогда работа с ними упроститься до работы с элементами массива

```js
let _myClassSingleton = Symbol();
class MyClass {
  constructor(enforcer) {
    if (enforcer != _myClassSingleton)
      throw "Cannot construct singleton";
  }
  static getInstance() {
    if (!this[_myClassSingleton]) {
      this[_myClassSingleton] = new MyClass(_myClassSingleton);
    }
    return this[_myClassSingleton];
  }
  someMethod() {
    console.log('MyClass/someMethod');
  }
}
let _myClassSingleton2 = Symbol();
class MyClass2 {
  constructor(enforcer) {
    if (enforcer != _myClassSingleton2)
      throw "Cannot construct singleton";
  }
  static getInstance() {
    if (!this[_myClassSingleton2]) {
      this[_myClassSingleton2] = new MyClass2(_myClassSingleton2);
    }
    return this[_myClassSingleton2];
  }
  someMethod() {
    console.log('MyClass2/someMethod');
  }
}

let applicationClasses = [MyClass, MyClass2];

let classes = applicationClasses.reduce((classes, c) => {
  classes[c.name] = c.getInstance();
  return classes
}, {});

classes.MyClass.someMethod();
classes.MyClass2.someMethod();
```

Comment: я сглупил и забыл что в массиве/объекте можно хранить имя класса не как строку а ссылку. Так что этот вариант подходит. Спасибо.

Comment: @СергейМишин, в любом случае это больше из разряда _потому что могу_, а не из-за какой-то практической ценности :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы все переусложняете.

Во-первых, нет смысла заводить класс для синглтона:

```
var MyObject = {
  someMethod() { console.log('MyClass/someMethod'); },
  // И никаких конструкторов с getInstance!
};
```

Во-вторых, нет никакого смысла писать имена переменных в массиве:

```
var objects = {
   MyObject: MyObject,
   MyObject2: MyObject2,
   MyObject3: MyObject3,
   MyObject4: MyObject4,
};
```

Comment: в третьих можно использовать [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: Да, знаю, что можно писать `var MyObject = {
  someMethod() { ... },  
};` Прост хотел сделать это на уровне ES6. Может это лишняя гонка за новым и привычном глазу. По поводу `var objects = {
   MyObject: MyObject,
   MyObject2: MyObject2,
  ...
};`  тоже знаю. Но для чего я хотел через цикл делать-чтоб как бы автоматически пробежалось и всё подключилось. Типа красивее выглядит, нежели вручную такой столбик городить некрасивый. То есть предлагаете принебречь излишней красотой в виде массива и цикла в угоду простоты добавления нужных классов в столбик? Типа не экономь на спичках? :)

Comment: @СергейМишин так ведь массив-то вы автоматически все равно не сформируете

Comment: @PavelMayorov да. но он просто спокойно в одну строку написан и не занимает много места :)

Comment: @СергейМишин литерал объекта тоже можно в одну строку написать :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да. Только в моем случае, если не переводить всё обратно с ES6 на ES5 всё, то получится `{MyClass1:MyClass1.getInstance(), MyClass2:MyClass2.getInstance(), MyClass3:MyClass3.getInstance() ... }` против `['MyClass1', 'MyClass2', 'MyClass3' ...]` . Тогда последний вопрос. Если не переводить обратно классы с ES6 на ES5, то варианты инициализации сводятся либо к `eval` либо большему извращению?

Comment: @СергейМишин синглтон тут лишний в любом случае. Даже `{ MyObject1: new MyClass1() }` выглядит симпатичнее.

Comment: @СергейМишин если хочется избежать повторяющегося кода - можно создать объект с классами, после чего пройтись по нему в цикле и вызвать new или getInstance

Comment: @PavelMayorov в принципе я тупанул. Точно же, В массиве/объекте можно хранить не строковое представление имен классов, а ссылки на них, как описал Grundy. Я что-то и забыл что так можно. Вам всё равно спасибо.